# Contextual code generation in Visual C# 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I type

```
ArrayList memberNames = new ArrayList() { "Jim", "John", "George" };
```

and Visual Studio tells me "ArrayList" cannot be found so I have to manually go to the top of the file and type

```
using System.Collections;
```

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to do this automatically?

In FlashDevelop, for instance, you press CTRL-SHIFT-1 and it automatically generates these missing references, a nice feature.

Comment: As a side note, you should probably use this instead: List<string> memberNames = new List<string>() {"Jim", "John", "George" };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHIFT-ALT-F10 Will activate the Smart Tag on the class, which will give you the options "using System.Collections", and "System.Collections.ArrayList".  It's typically two keystrokes to add a using.

Edit:  Seems I had a mangled keyboard profile.  Updated the key combo to the default.  Thanks to Alan for pointing it out.

Comment: Funnily, people upvoted this without even trying the key combo. It's Shift+Alt+F10 (the one given here is for the editor context menu) by default, at least in the Visual C# keyboard layout. ckramer, can you please edit your answer?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> brings up a pop-up menu with "using System.Collections", and "System.Collections.ArrayList".

If you want to find a keyboard shortcut, choose Tools: Options and navigate down to Environment: Keyboard. However, it can be a challenge to figure out what they've called the thing you're looking for. (The one you asked about is obviously View.ShowSmartTag, right?)

**Update:** From comments and other posts, I just learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> also brings up the same menu. I guess not all the keyboard shortcuts appear in the keyboard options dialog.

Comment: Ctrl-. also brings up that menu.

Answer (score 1):

**CTRL+.** also activates the Smart Tag, which might be more intuitive.